# scikit learn classifies stopwords

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

Here is the example where there is step by step procedure to make system learn and classify input data.

It classifies correctly for given 5 datasets domains. Additionally it also classifies stopwords.

e.g

Input : `docs_new = ['God is love', 'what is where']`

Output :

```
'God is love' => soc.religion.christian
'what is where' => soc.religion.christian
```

Here `what is where` should not be classified as it contains only stopwords. How scikit learn functions in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what classifier you are using. But let's assume you use a Naive Bayes classifier.

In this case, the sample is labeled as the class for which the posterior probability is maximum given a particular pattern of words.
And the posterior probability is calculated as

posterior = likelihood x prior

Note that the evidence term was dropped since it is constant). Additionally, there is an additive smoothening to avoid scenarios where the likelihood is zero.
Anyway, if you have only stop words in your input text, the likelihood is constant for all classes and the **posterior probability is entirely determined by your prior probability**. So, what basically happens is that a Naive Bayes classifier (if the priors were estimated from the training data) will assign the class label that occurs most often in the training data.

Comment: so, if input query is outof domain, the same scenario will take place. right?

Comment: Basically, every time you encounter something completely "new" that is text of words that are all not in the training set, the class-conditional probabilities (likelihoods) are 0 -- and considering the additive smoothening it will be a constant term >0. So, everything (the posterior and the decision rule that is based on the posterior) depends on the (class) priors.

Comment: thanks a lot for this explaination. Can you please give any scikit reference for this if exists

Comment: Sure, have a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html . Btw., I am preparing a more detailed tutorial on Naive Bayes classification explaining those concepts and eventually applying them for spam filtering using scikit learn. It's far from being finished, but here is a preview if it is helpful: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/bayes_smsspam/machine_learning/scikit-learn/scikit_bayes_smsspam.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

A classifier always predicts one of the classes that it saw during its training phase, by definition. I don't know what you did to produce the classifier, but most likely it's just predicting the majority class for any sample without interesting features; that what naive Bayes, linear SVMs and other typical text classifiers do.

Comment: Yes, ideally it should do what you mentioned, and also I have followed the given procedure. But still it classifies `stopwords` into category. If possible just give 2-3 minutes to test this example http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html of training classifier and do make input query `what is where`. And see what is output. The result is strange for me

Comment: @user2129623 That's the expected behavior. Any document, even an empty document, will be assigned a class, as I detailed in the answer.

Comment: okay, I agree. But if text in query does not match with any trained class, then would it randomly assign any of the class or what. That is what I wanted to know

Comment: As I said, it will assign the majority class when none of the features match.

Answer (score 0):

Standard text classification uses TfidfVectorizer to transform text to tokens and to vectors of features as input to classifier. 
One of the init parameters is stop_words, in case stop_words='english' the vectorizer will produce no features for the sentence 'what is where'. 
Stop words are matched lexically against every input token using a built in english stop words list you can examine here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/stop_words.py

Comment: @D: thanks, that is what I also understand; vectorizer will produce no features for the sentence 'what is where'. But still it gives 33% for films. For 4 domains the result is `'what is what' => films => 0.333333333333
'what is what' => laptops => 0.333333333333
'what is what' => medicine => 0.166666666667
'what is what' => mobile_phones => 0.166666666667
`

Comment: It depends on the exact setup of the vectorizer the classifier and on the training data you used to train your classifier. The results you see are just initial distributions of each of the categories. Probably the proportion of the trained data for each category.

Comment: Yes, and it is not only the case if you are using Tf-idf but also Count vectorizers etc.